# NameError: name 'keras_applications' is not defined

Tags: python, keras

When I use keras to save my model and loading then I get this error message

```
code:model=load_model('model.h5') 
it cause error(
if hasattr(keras_applications, 'get_submodules_from_kwargs'):
NameError: name 'keras_applications' is not defined).
```

So I took a look at the `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\applications\__init__.py"` and it includes the `import keras_applications` and 
`keras version:2.2.4` statements.

So the keras_applications exists but it cause an error and I don't know the reason why?
My keras_application version currently is 1.0.8 but I tried it with 1.0.6 as well and the same error shows up.

```
model = load_model('model.h5')

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 743, in call
    return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\applications\__init__.py", line 23, in wrapper
    if hasattr(keras_applications, 'get_submodules_from_kwargs'):
NameError: name 'keras_applications' is not defined
```

Comment: This thread may help https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21518

Answer (score 0):

in `Tensorflow 2.0+,` `import keras` by the code below-

```
from tensorflow import keras,
```

Then use keras as it is. and it will work fine.